# Warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally

Tags: performance, debugging, warnings, xcode4.2, ipod

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and use real device (iPod touch) for debugging. Debugging process is really slow and I get tons of messages in console every time I run debugging:

```
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x2d03]
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

**EDITED:** IOS on iPod is 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the iPod running? I'm guessing it's one that you don't have the SDK for in Xcode, hence it's having to read things from the device itself. Download the right SDK to Xcode and things should improve.

Comment: @JaneSales Are you really 92?!